# How to track events inside an app for link to store with utm params?

Tags: flutter, firebase-analytics

I can build link to an app in PlayStore with utm params.

I need to know:

- How many installations happen for this link.
- How many events happen inside an app for this link. For example successful registrations. Is it possible? How to track it?

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: I'm using firebase analytics. In conversions you can check `first_open` event, and if you mark any other event as conversion you will be able add utm params as filter.

Comment: any example to how to check with screen shots? I am new to analytics.